# Is there way a can put timeout on mongodb server idle connections?

Tags: mongodb

For different mongo drivers(nodejs , java), it provides a way to set idle time out and some other configs. I want to apply this on mongodb server, eg. in case of mysql i can set up idle connection timeout after that mysql server disconnects the connection irrespective of client timeout.
is there any such config in mongo?

Comment: Interesting question.  MongoDB strives for high availability.  Your question asks the opposite - high unavailability.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass timeout in option parameter as below:

```
var uri =  ‘mongodb://[user:pass@]host[:27017]/[database]’;
var options = { server:
               { socketOptions: 
                    { 
                        socketTimeoutMS: SOCKET_TIME_OUT_MS, 
                        connectTimeoutMS: CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS 
                    }
                }
              };
MongoClient.connect(uri, options, function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
    console.log("Error connecting DB");
});
```

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Comment: My question was , is there any setting at server level, because connection can be closed from any side(client or server) and i want server to have more control over connection.